# how to invoke a shell function with sudo permission

Tags: sudo

There is a shell function `add_book` in my `.zshrc`. I need to invoke this function with sudo permission. But when I invoke `sudo add_book` I get the following error:

```
sudo: add_book: command not found
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

You can run the program by getting root permission in advanced with this command:

```
sudo -i
```

Then run your command when it turns into root@hostname#

Comment: Not sure. I haven't tried it, but -i option stands for "interactive" and loads the TARGET user's profile. So if a normal user defines a custom command on his shell, -i simply ignores that and looks for commands available for root. I repeat, I haven't tried it!

Answer (score 0):

```
# cat /tmp/moo 
function moo { echo moo; }
# unset moo
# type moo 
-bash: type: moo: not found
# sudo -u root bash -c 'source /tmp/moo; moo' 
moo
```